# alt+shift+n keyword int terminal

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys

I've found something wierd in bash.

Does anyone know what does `shift + alt + n` do in a bash?

When I press these keys, first it writes `:`, and if I press them again, it writes `^[N`. (Same with `alt + shift + p`).

With `alt + shift + {` it shows all files as an special array (test it, you'll understand why it's special), and using `alt + shift + ,` it writes `traceroute google.com` (I think it's one of my previous commands, but why does `alt + shift + ,` show this command?).

I searched a lot, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The shift is not doing anything useful.

`alt + n` searches through your history forward; fetches the next command.

Comment: Assume I pressed `alt+p` to search for a command containing `something` and I found the last command containing `something`. How I repeat the same search to find the previous command to that one, which contains the *same* string?

Comment: How about `alt + shift + { `?

Comment: Use `ctrl + r` for reverse searching. @FedonKadifeli